# My ApplicationDbContext is null for some reason

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I get the error System.NullReferenceException.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL.Maintenance.DoMaintenance()

But the context code is the same as on scaffolded pages, so not sure what I need to do.  Any help is appreciated.

The code is:

```
namespace Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL

{   
    public class Maintenance
    {
        private readonly Club.Data.ApplicationDbContext Context; 

        public Maintenance(ApplicationDbContext context) 
     IN DEBUG MODE context IS INDICATED 
     AS OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT.  
     HOW DO I FIX THIS.
        {
            Context = context;
        }
        public Maintenance()
        {

        }
        
        public void DoMaintenance()
        {
            //Parse Maintenance table and action those items
            //where Active=True and ActionDate has passed
           
            //==================================
            //Retrieve list of rows in Maintenance table
            var maintenances = Context.Maintenance;  PROGRAM FAILS ON THIS LINE.
```

I imagine I am missing something fundamental as I am 'learning by doing'.  The lines that call up the DoMaintenance routine are located in root/Pages/Index, which is a scaffolded page.  The DoMaintenance routine is called from the following lines in the root/Pages/index.cshtml page:

```
     public void OnGet()
     {
        Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance();//Create new instance
        maintenance.DoMaintenance();
     }
```

AND Startup.cs includes the lines

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: check you injected your dbcontext properly.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you call the Maintenance? Do you register the Maintenance as the services? If possible, please post related register service codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and codes, I found you have register the dbcontext as a service in your application that means if you want to use it, you should inject the dbcontext into your Maintenance class.

Normally, we will create a service as BLL service in asp.net core.

Then we could register the service in the startup.cs and inject it in the razor page.

I suggest you could try to modify the Maintenance class as below codes shows:

You could create a interface called IMaintenance:

```
public  interface IMaintenance
{
    public void DoMaintenance();
}
```

Then you could let Maintenance inherit IMaintenance as below:

```
public class Maintenance : IMaintenance
{
    private readonly TestDbcontext Context;


    public Maintenance(TestDbcontext testDbcontext ) {
        Context = testDbcontext;
    }

    public void DoMaintenance() {

        var maintenances = Context.Employees.ToList() ;

        
    }
}
```

At last, you could register the Maintenance  as service in startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<TestDbcontext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);


        services.AddTransient<IMaintenance, Maintenance>();

    }
```

You could directly use the Maintenance in razor pages like below, the asp.net core dependency injection will inject the dbcontext automatically into Maintenance.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> _localizer;
    private readonly IMaintenance _maintance;

    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }


    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> localizer, IMaintenance maintance)
    {

        _logger = logger;
        _localizer = localizer;
        _maintance = maintance;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        _maintance.DoMaintenance()
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Club.Pages
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
         private readonly IMaintenance  _maintenance;

        public IndexModel (IMaintenance<IndexModel> maintenance)  
        {
            _maintenance = maintenance;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
           _maintenance.DoMaintenance();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brando.  I am working my way through this and trying to understand the process - including reading https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/dependency-injection.  This is taking some concentration and I will get back to you again shortly.  I very much appreciate the effort you have provided in responding to my question.

Comment: I have update my answer. This is no need to use `private readonly IMaintenance<IndexModel>_maintance; ` , we could directly use  `private readonly IMaintenance _maintance;` and `public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, ForumManageContext dbcontext , IMaintenance maintance)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbcontext = dbcontext;
            _maintance = maintance;
        }`

Comment: Hi Brando.  I became aware there was a copy of IMaintenance.cs in my root/Pages folder.  I must have copied it from Services as part of exploring the issue and forgot to delete it later.  When I did delete it your original reply worked beautifully.  Much appreciated and my apologies for the later side track.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to inject your context and since there's default ctor, everything works fine without setting Context property.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Context>(() => ...));
    }
```

Comment: Startup.cs contains:   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Comment: @AlanLaird, try for now to remove default constructor. In general, using multiple constructors is not advised when combined with Dependency Injection.

Comment: Hi Viktor, thanks for your comment.  in further exploration I have observed that the following lines do not fire:  private readonly Club.Data.ApplicationDbContext Context; 

        public Maintenance(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }